# [PHP]Count down to specific times on a specific day

Tags: php, timer, countdown, countdowntimer

I'm making an automatic countdown to an event that starts 2-3 times a day on diffrent times.

The event starts every 7 hours, so one day there are 4 events and the other 3.

**Example:**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/IvYbh.png

```
$monday    = array( '02:00', '09:00', '16:00', '23:00' );
$tuesday   = array( '06:00', '13:00', '20:00'          );
$wednesday = array( '03:00', '10:00', '17:00'          );
$thursday  = array( '00:00', '07:00', '14:00', '21:00' );
$friday    = array( '04:00', '11:00', '18:00'          );
$saturday  = array( '01:00', '08:00', '15:00', '22:00' );
$sunday    = array( '05:00', '12:00', '19:00'          );
```

How to make the countdown run to the next event?

Example: if it is Monday, 01:30, it should say 30min left

I already made the countdown part:

```
 $hours = floor($this->sec / 3600);
 $minutes = floor(($this->sec / 60) % 60);
 $seconds = $this->sec % 60;
 return "$hours" . ' hours ' . "$minutes" .  ' minutes ' . "$seconds" . ' seconds';
```

**Update**: I know that the PHP won´t update just on itself. I will refresh the page manually.

Comment: Which bit do you need a tip with? What's wrong with the countdown code that you have?

Comment: It seems to me that if you want this to be shown on a web page you need to do this in javascript. Otherwise if I leave the page open for an hour the coundown will not change.

Comment: Sorry but this looks far to much like a **code it for me** request. Vote to close as to broad.

Comment: @petethepagan-gerbil I know how to make the countdown work with manualy filling a date in. But i want make something that it will countdown to the next event.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I understand your javascript comment.

Answer (score 1):

```
function days_hours_minutes_from_now($date)
{
  $now = time();
  $your_date = strtotime($date);
  $datediff = $your_date - $now;
  echo "days: " .floor($datediff/(60*60*24));
  echo " hours: " .floor($datediff/(60*60)) % 24; //hours
  echo " minutes: " .floor($datediff/(60)) % 60; //minutes
  echo " seconds: " .$datediff % 60; //seconds
}

days_hours_minutes_from_now("2015-08-19 13:52:28");
```

> days: 1 hours: 0 minutes: 14 seconds: 56

Hasn't been tested thoroughly, but should be close to what you're looking for.

You need to compare the time against when the event starts to get a countdown.

However, as RiggsFolly rightly pointed out, unless you do this in javascript, your countdown isn't going to update in the user's browser unless they refresh the page.

**Edit:**

Now, if you wanted to ensure you always returned the time remaining until the *next* event, then you can loop through a series of dates, sorted in ascending order, and return the first result where the day is a non-negative value. If any date exceeds the current date/time, day will equal -1

Comment: Maybe i was too unclear, i already got that part but i need a function that automaticly gives me the date of the next event.

Comment: @user4375106 I'll include a solution in my answer shortly.

Comment: How do that foreach trick without hardcoded dates then? I understand i can make a foreach until its not negative anymore, but i dont want to put in dates for the next 12 months. And it is possible because its every week the same times

Comment: @user4375106 you still need a starting point to generate your dates from, so your array could contain the start hour for each day of the week, and you compare that to the current time. You need a point of reference.  So an array of days, and each day is an array of times.

Comment: How does php know then that we are in a new week, example: Its friday 8pm and the next event is next friday 2pm next week. How does it know that its need to return 6 days ... and not - 6h.

Comment: @user4375106 I'm afraid your question is too broad for me to be of any further help with this. These are not specific questions about coding problems, but implementation.